# Why are the system requirements significantly higher for the linux port of Team Fortress 2?

Tags: windows, games, steam, system-requirements, porting

Why are the system requirements significantly higher for the linux port of Team Fortress 2?

Copy-and-pasted from: http://store.steampowered.com/app/440/

Windows Minimum:

```
    OS: Windows® 7 (32/64-bit)/Vista/XP
    Processor: 1.7 GHz Processor or better
    Memory: 512 MB RAM
    DirectX: Version 8.1
```

SteamOS + Linux Minimum:

```
    OS: Ubuntu 12.04
    Processor: Dual core from Intel or AMD at 2.8 GHz
    Memory: 1 GB RAM
    Graphics: nVidia GeForce 8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeon HD2600/3600 (Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310, AMD 12.11), OpenGL 2.1
```

Comment: How do we know? Ask Steam.

Comment: @muru I thought this might be due to some, linux-specific artifact of porting, which is known in the linux community. But sure, I'll ask on steam.

Answer (score 2):

Running the ported games requires a lot of overhead. They use a wrapper to get DirectX games running through OpenGL.

Look at the requirements for [Dota 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/570/):

```
MS Windows:
OS: Windows 7
Processor: Dual core from Intel or AMD at 2.8 GHz
Memory: 4 GB RAM
Graphics: nVidia GeForce 8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeon HD2600/3600
DirectX: Version 9.0c
Network: Broadband Internet connection
Storage: 8 GB available space
Sound Card: DirectX Compatible 
~~
Linux:
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Processor: Dual core from Intel or AMD at 2.8 GHz
Memory: 4 GB RAM
Graphics: nVidia Geforce 8600/9600GT (Driver v331), AMD HD 2xxx-4xxx (Driver mesa 10.5.9), AMD HD 5xxx+ (Driver mesa 10.5.9 or Catalyst 15.7), Intel HD 3000 (Driver mesa 10.6)
Network: Broadband Internet connection
Storage: 8 GB available space
Sound Card: OpenAL Compatible Sound Card
```

Dota 2 reborn was not a cut+paste port, instead Source 2 natively supports OpenGL. The system requirements are very similar.

**tl;dr:** Some games have a DirectX wrapper which have a lot of overhead.